# AngularJS ng-repeat is not working with select option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My `http` part it work it get the value there is not problem with it but when i use them on select option it doesn't show  it shows me in the inspect it shows all the values

```
 $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "php/home_page.php"
      }).success(function(result) {
        $scope.populars = result;
      });
```

```html
<select  data-placeholder="Choose Location"  >

    <option  ng-repeat="reserve in populars"> {{reserve.name}}</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are saving a $http response object on $scope.populars, not an object array as you are expecting in the html snippet.

I suggest:

```
 $http({
    // request info
  }).success(function(response) {
    $scope.populars = response.data;
  });
```

Assuming the data your API responds has the form:

```
data = [
  {
    name: "data",
    // other object members
  }
]
```